# What is the proper way to pronounce basket?

Tags: pronunciation

For the word basket, is the second syllable pronounced like get or git?

Comment: depends who you ask. Even in just the UK you'll hear both, & also an intermediate version with a schwa ə .

Comment: Collins gives [audio examples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/basket) of both US and UK pronunciation (no IPA, but clearly they both end like ***git***, not ***get***). And [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/basket) points out that another *significant* aspect of variability is the choice between **bas-kit** and **bah-skit** (as a Brit, I associate the former with speakers from the North).

Comment: As a northerner, I hear sket or skət when spoken by southerners/RP. It's slight, but it's there, to my ear. I only really hear skit from northerners. Similar to waistcoat/weskət. [I'm from the north but I live in the south]

Comment: If you haven't used it yet, [Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/basket/#en) is a great resource for questions like this.

Comment: & the first one on Forvo says sket. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is an audio pronunciation guide for the word in both *British* and *American* English here:

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/basket

But even in the UK there are many different accents and this is a word that can be pronounced differently.

I believe how you pronounce the *first* syllable has a bearing on how the second is pronounced. The main difference between American and British pronunciations of words in general is the length of vowel sounds.

Look at your lip pattern, or mouth shape as you pronounce the first syllable.

- If you pronounce the first syllable to sound like "bar" I believe you are more likely to pronounce the second syllable to rhyme with "skit".
- Whereas if you pronounce the first syllable with a more clipped vowel sound, as in "bat"; or the American way which sounds more like "bear" to me, this makes for a wider mouth shape and I believe you are more likely to pronounce the second syllable to rhyme with "get".

Summing up, I would say that **both** pronunciations of the second syllable are common *and* acceptable; however I would say that they would have to be consistent with how you pronounced the first syllable. Pronouncing it as "bear-skit" sounds a little unnatural in any accent.

Answer (score -1):

The pronunciation of unstressed "weak" vowels is fairly variable between different accents, and even between different speakers of the "same" accent. It's fine to pronounce "basket" with either [ɪ] or [ə].

The OED entry for "basket", which was first published 1885 and has not yet been fully updated, gives the vowel in the second syllable as /ɪ/.

But many speakers have a "weak vowel merger" whereby the sound /ɪ/ has been replaced with the sound /ə/ (the schwa) in some or all fully unstressed syllables. The "weak vowel merger" is particularly common in American English, although I don't think all American speakers have fully merged unstressed /ɪ/ into /ə/. Even for speakers who do not have the weak vowel merger in general, there may be some words where some people have /ə/ and others have /ɪ/.

Note that the schwa sound /ə/ is not the same as the unreduced "short e" sound /ɛ/ that many speakers use in the stressed pronunciation of the word "get" (/gɛt/).